# Is there anything special about a graph with the golden ratio in its spectrum?

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, golden-ratio

Given a simple connected graph $g$ with adjacency matrix $\mathbf{A}$. Let the spectrum $\lambda_1 < \lambda_2 < \ldots < \lambda_N$ be the eigenvalues of the equation $\mathbf{A} v=\lambda v$. For lack of a better word, let a graph be called *golden* if there is an eigenvalue such that $\lambda_i = n \phi$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}, |n| > 0$ and $\phi$ is the [golden ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio).

Do *golden* graphs have any special symmetry or property? I computed all simple connected *golden* graphs of order 6 as a starting point:

[image]

Comment: The graph in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/234313/construction-of-a-graph/234416#234416) has two pairs of $\phi$-$\phi^{-1}$ eigenvalues. It's obtained by taking the graph in the right bottom corner (in your question) and adding a seventh vertex adjacent to the three degree $2$ vertices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The experimental evidence indicates that "most" graphs have characteristic polynomial irreducible over the rationals. Thus most graphs do not have the golden ratio as a root. Note also that we do not have a nice characterization of graphs with 1 (say) as an eigenvalue, perhaps we should not expect too much for the golden ratio.

Comment: Can provide a reference for "experimental evidence indicates that most graphs have characteristic polynomial irreducible over the rationals"?

Comment: No reference. You just generate graphs on $n$ vertices at random, compute the characteristic polynomials and stuff them into the software of your choice. These days I use sage. The fist person I know who did this was Laci Babai.

Answer (score 1):

The minimal polynomial of $n \phi$ is $z^2 - n z - n^2$, so a graph is "golden" iff its characteristic polynomial is divisible by $z^2 - n z - n^2$ for some nonzero integer $n$.

Comment: Right, that explains why they are relatively common. I was interested if the graphs themselves have any special symmetry. For example, none of the graphs seem particularly dense (in that they are planar or nearly so). These seems to be true for the graphs of order 7 that I examined as well.